# Resize root partition on Linux CentOS 6.7

Tags: linux, centos, partition

I have a 1.5TB SSD for CentOS 6.7 . But when I created a partition, I just created a small storage size for root, but the `/home` partition had lots of capacity. Could I move the available capacity from the `/home` partition to the root partition WITHOUT LOSING any files on the SERVER? It's around 50GB for the root partition.

Comment: Please show at least output of `lsblk` and `df -h`. In short: it's possible, but could be dangerous and could consume substantial time, depending on how exactly your storage is laid out. Also instructions could be different. So I'm asking for that information.

Comment: Also, I am curious what did you do with the server so you filled up a 50GB root partiton. For example, mine is around 28 GiB and only 7 GiB is used. 50 GB /root is *more than enough* for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Delete a root partition used a fdisk, and create new partitionts. You dates is saved and not deleted!
For example:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
Command (m for help): p
Command (m for help): d
Command (m for help): n (used defaults address of a sectors)
Command (m for help): w
```

then userd `resize2fs /dev/whatever`.
It is resize root partition with saves dates.

Comment: Nice. How this helps to take capacity from the /home filesystem, while preserving the data there?

Comment: Deleting the root partition sounds like a somewhat dangerous thing to do, especially on a running system. Since this is a delicate procedure that probably requires keeping track of certain start and stop numbers (right?), could you please update your answer with slightly more details?

Comment: No, in principle it is correct way to enlarge a partition when there is a free space block immediately following it, even when it is mounted. But this needs attention to start sector, as you mentioned, and moreover, I don't understand how he intends to take a space from /home. Who said there *is* a free space block currently immediately after /root parition? Also, who said filesystems are on raw partitions and not, say, on LVs? CentOS installs on LVM by default.